# Oracle sql query, concatenate fileds with CASE section

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, case, toad

I'm currently generating SQL insert statements from more than one tables, and in the generated data I need to use a CASE statement, like this:

```
select 'INSERT INTO TABLE1 (f1, f2, f3, f4 ...) values ('
       ||t.f1||','
       ||CASE
             WHEN t.f2 > 0 THEN '1'
             ELSE '0'
         END CASE
  from table2 t , table3 t3
```

But at this point if I want to continue my statement with `... END CASE||','|| ....` I can't run the query anymore, as TOAD complains about not finding the FROM keyword.

A quick solution was to separate the ouput into fields, then save it to text, and edit, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use END instead of END CASE

```
select 'INSERT INTO TABLE1 (f1, f2, f3, f4 ...) values ('
       ||t.f1||','
       ||CASE
             WHEN t.f2 > 0 THEN '1'
             ELSE '0'
         END||','||t.f2
  from table2 t , table3 t3
```

Answer (score 1):

For some similar situations, the "decode" function works quite well.

You might be able to feed the expression (t.f2 > 0) into a decode,  and then translate 
'T' into '1' and 'F' into '0'.

I haven't tried this.